# Running .tcl file multiple times with different start and stop times for traffic generators

Tags: tcl, simulation, ns2

I've created the following code to run a tcl script multiple times in NS2.The code is executed many times but the start and stop times for the traffic generator doesn't  change from one run to the other .What is wrong with my code?

```
set ns [new Simulator]
for {set i 1} {$i<5} {incr i} {
   .....
set min 0
set max 10
set min1 10
set max1 20
set start [expr rand()*($max-$min)]
set stop [expr rand()*($max1-$min1)+$min1]
$ns at $start "ftp start"
$ns at $stop "ftp stop"
puts $outfile "$start $stop"
}
$ns run
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I have no idea about ns2, but a quick glance at a tutorial suggests you should pass a value, not a variable name to the _at_ method. So, for example: `$ns at $start "ftp start"`

Comment: "stop" will usually be like : `set time_duration 100`  or `set opt(stop)   90` .... and is maximum time. So a stop time 100 can be a simulation time = 0.1 .. 2 seconds. ... A fixed stop can be added : `$ns_ at $opt(stop).0002 "puts \"NS EXITING...\" ; $ns_ halt"` ... `$ns_ at $opt(stop).0001 "stop"` .... Examples https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing

Comment: @Schelte Bron You're right but that was a typing mistake .I'll fix it.